# How to have IntelliJ formatter wrap code after the . separator?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

Is it possible to configure the IntelliJ java formatter to wrap lines **after** the `.` separator instead of before it?

Example

```
String s = new StringBuilder("User{").
    append("Name=").append(name).append(",")
    append("Email=").append(email).append(",")
    append("Phone=").append(phone).
    append("}").toString();
```

Yes this formatting is odd, but I have inherited this formatting along with the CheckStyle [NoWhitespaceBeforeCheck](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/whitespace/NoWhitespaceBeforeCheck.html) on a DOT which enforces it.

We do use Eclipse formatting so if there is an option in there, that would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. There's a feature request for that, you can follow it here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-123881